# How is model.fit affected in a for-loop

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am implementing walk-forward optimization for a time series. I understand splitting the set to train-test with 20-30% reserved for testing, but for time series i cant randomly split nor can i choose the last portion of the data as it's not indicative of changes happening in the majority of the training set. If i put a model.fit into a for-loop how is it affected when looping over my segmented dates? Does it get reset or does it keep the previous tests?

Here's an idea (Its not meant to run, just something to see the concept)

```
for date in seg_dates:
    x_train = dataframe.iloc[date-timeframeLength : date, x_varColumn]
    y_train = dataframe.iloc[date-timeframeLength: date, y_varColumn]
    model = LinearRegression()
    model.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

Comment: what library are you using? I think that each call to `model.fit()` will return a new result for the linear regression. They shouldn't affect each other. You will just get a new `m` and `b` for each set of `(x, y)` pairs.

Comment: Using sklearn's library

Comment: Your example would create a new regression regardless, because you override `model` with a fresh `LinearRegression` in the loop.  The question would be better if you initialized the model outside the loop, then repeatedly fit it inside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

the `.fit` method will 'reset' the model to be trained on only the values in x_train and y_train.

if you want to train it on an extended dataset, then you should make both x_train and y_train as lists and `append` them inside the loop before training , (instead of training on each iteration).

```py
x_train = []
y_train = []
for date in seg_dates:
    x_train.append(dataframe.iloc[date-timeframeLength : date, x_varColumn])
    y_train.append(dataframe.iloc[date-timeframeLength: date, y_varColumn])
model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

you can also apply `sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split` to split data into train and test before the `.fit` line.

as for training on time series, I think the best method is to split the time series into a lot of 'windows' and your 'sample' will be your 'windowed data'.

edit: replaced `extend` with `append`, since you want the data to be a time series, and not single valued data points.

Comment: Does it actually "reset" the model or is the `model.fit()` stateless?

Comment: the model parameters are re-initialized, before being retrained if they need to be initialized, so no previous data is memorized, needless to say that `LinearRegression` like other algorithms don't have an initial state, and just obtains the parameters from the training data directly (least squares fitting), so it will also be 'reset' when trained.

Comment: In `scikit-learn`, `model.fit()` generally re-initializes the weights when it is called. Some models that fit with gradient descent, such as `SGDRegressor` and `MLPRegressor` allow this to be disabled by passing `warm_start=True`, which will initialize training using the previous weights.